# oAuth : Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2 using jdbctokenstore

Tags: spring, oauth

We are facing an issue duplicate access token in spring oauth, we put synchronized token service by extending DefaultTokenServices, but its not resolved.
We use Oauth Version : oauth2:1.0.0
Spring Version:3.2.5.

Refer the image : how data can be stored in backend.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1098585/14854150/2be8edda-0cac-11e6-8eb6-4383583c8c97.png]

Answer (score 1):

We to had a same problem. I fixed it by setting  `authentication_id` in the table `oauth_access_token` to primary to solve this.

There is a race condition in org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices#refreshAccessToken which results in entries with duplicate authentication_id in the table oauth_access_token (even after 2.0.5). This occurs when two threads access the database at the same time but both still get the authentication for the old refresh-token (tokenStore.readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(refreshToken)).

```
create table oauth_access_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token LONGVARBINARY,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(256),
  client_id VARCHAR(256),
  authentication LONGVARBINARY,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(256)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Currently we upgrade the oauth version from 1.0.0 to 2.0.9, i need a clarification, In which version this issue have been resolved.  From my analyzation, dsyer told in 2.0.4 version this issues have resolved(Follow the link : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/276).

Comment: The information is available in my answer, The problem is there even after 2.0.5

Comment: I just confirmed thanks Backtrack, I think this issue not resolved in oauth2, all the version have this issue. I upgraded the version from 1.0.0 to 2.0.4, still i got this error(set primary key for authentication_id in oauth_access_token). when will this issue can be fix. But how @Dsyer told this issue can be fixed in 2.0.4..? :(

Comment: @Priya,  Did you try adding primary key and check it. Did it not solve your problem. ?

Comment: yes i added primary key and check , its not solve my problem.Shows error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_PK) violated\n; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_PK) violated\n"

Comment: No no, The thing is, Did it insert duplicate record into Table ?

Comment: Hi @Priya, It is expected one.  Then the second attempt to refresh the token fails with a DuplicateKeyException which you can handle. This is not that bad since duplicate refresh requests aren't that good anyway.  refer this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/463

Comment: I have similar problem. My table already has the authentication_id set as primary key. There's no way it has duplicates. I think the problem is somewhere else, but I'm not sure where. Any ideas?